# How to view IP addresses blocked under Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

I've managed to use below command to block ip address:

```
/sbin/route add -host 111.111.111.11 reject
```

How do I view if this is in the list? How do I view all IP's that are currently blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the routing table with:

```
netstat -r
netstat -rn
```

Answer (score 0):

running

```
/sbin/route
```

will display the current rules. You should see something like this:

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo /sbin/route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
KD111111111011. -               255.255.255.255 !H    0      -        0 -
```

This isn't too viewer friendly, but the Destination is the IP without any .'s in it. 11 became 011 because it uses 3 places for each octet.